# VB.net 2008 and Crystal Reports 11 dynamicaly change graphic location

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using VB.NET2008 and Crystal Reports 11.5. I have created rpt in crystal reports app and created Picture Object. also gave the **Graphic Location** formula as follows;

```
{pic_path.path_name} + "\" + {reg_emp.emp_qid} + ".jpg"
```

pic_path.path_name and reg_emp.emp_qid has the file locationa path something as follows;

```
"C:\bin" + "\" + "2345" + ".jpg"
```

It is working fine with the report. But when I import it on VB.NET and use below code to display the rpt;

```
Dim cryRpt As New rpt_labor_card ' this is the rpt file
    cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds) 'ds has the all data to be displayed in report

    rpt_view.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    rpt_view.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    rpt_view.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    rpt_view.Show()
```

But picture is not displaying in report and the Graphics Location is not available in Format Object > Picture.

What can I do to display picture in rpt file ?

Thank you,

Sameera

Comment: ok let me know are you taking the picture by code or it just static picture?

Comment: dataset has the path to picture location. I have inserted picture with a default image. my problem is Graphics Location is not available inside vb.net rpt

Comment: check following links 
 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15756aec-faef-4c24-af6a-136ce771bd31/help-adding-a-picure-to-crystal-report-at-run-time?forum=vscrystalreports

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21095/Image-in-Crystal-Reports

Comment: try to load that picture in your database and pass it to directly crystal report. And use that field directly instead of taking Graphics Object.

Comment: I have already picture in my rpt. I want to change it according to dataset picture URL. also I am using VB.NET2008

Comment: Please Keep it in your mind that rpt works fine with Crystal Reports program Graphics Location. But When I import it in to VB.NET, Graphics Location option not available.

Comment: Try this.
 Insert an image to the report this image only for a placeholder and  Change the image’s Graphic Location by using following step

• right click image

• select Format Graphic…

• select Picture tab

• click the conditional-formula button 

• set the formula’s text to the name of the formula or parameter field that will contain the image’s URL

• save the formula and click the OK button
and save the rpt file

this worked for me should have to work.

cheers

Comment: Yes.. I done it with the rpt and it is working fine. As I explained many times, after I import rpt to inside my VB.NET project, I can't see Graphics Location in Format Graphic......

Comment: My requirement is very simple. I just want to know, how can I change the picture URL in Picture Object since Graphic Location is not available in rpt file located inside VB.NET2008 project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your crystal viewer in your program. Since the graphic location is not there, there is no way to dynamically load images. I have researched this for quite a while now, and still have not come up with a solution.